# Hitting CPU cache for better performance in C++

Tags: c++, cpu-cache

Is working on continuous buffers preferred for CPU caching?

I am trying to write an application that does several operations on image (some very local such as shifting, derivatives and some between results like subtraction).
I have a large buffer for the results (each calculation has the shape of an image, so I start with allocation of X * image shape bytes)

What should I do for maximizing the CPU cache hits?

Comment: *Is working on continuous buffers preferred for CPU caching?* Yes.  Cache is the fastest memory you have.  If you can stay in cache, you will be as fast as you can be, well at least in terms of read-write.

Comment: You may also want to consider using the GPU.

Comment: Not just caching, but the prefetcher too. Having a predictable and clear data access pattern helps the CPU prefetch your data before you need it. That alone can save thousands of cycles of waiting for RAM when the CPU could have had the data ready for you.

Comment: if the image operation is more complex than just subtraction, for example smoothing/filtering, you should consider multi-threading

Comment: Try breaking up your image into small squares.  Perform as many functions on that square as possible.  Then move onto the next square.  Maybe better by row; only benchmarking will tell.  In other words, do as much as possible while the data is in the cache, preventing cache reloads.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, working on a continuous array is more likely to hit cache.
You may want to arrange your data in a continuous way:
For instance:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

const int SIZE = 3;

int main(){
    uint8_t buffer_2d[SIZE][SIZE];
    uint8_t* buffer_1d = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(buffer_2d); // or just do uint8_t buffer_1d[SIZE*SIZE];
    const auto base = &(buffer_2d[0][0]);
    for (int y=0;y<SIZE;++y){
        for (int x=0;x<SIZE;++x){
            std::cout << "x: " << x << " y: " << y << " offset for [x][y]: " << &(buffer_2d[x][y]) - base << " offset for [y][x]: " << &(buffer_2d[y][x]) - &(buffer_2d[0][0]) << " offset for [y*SIZE+x]: " << &(buffer_1d[y*SIZE+x]) - base <<  std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Treating the array as a human natural `[x][y]` array would not be efficient, as the data is not aligned this way, the efficient approach would be to use `[y][x]` or work on the array as a single dimension array and treat the index as `y*LINE_SIZE + x`.
Here is the output for this test showing exactly that:

```
x: 0 y: 0 offset for [x][y]: 0 offset for [y][x]: 0 offset for [y*SIZE+x]: 0
x: 1 y: 0 offset for [x][y]: 3 offset for [y][x]: 1 offset for [y*SIZE+x]: 1
x: 2 y: 0 offset for [x][y]: 6 offset for [y][x]: 2 offset for [y*SIZE+x]: 2
x: 0 y: 1 offset for [x][y]: 1 offset for [y][x]: 3 offset for [y*SIZE+x]: 3
x: 1 y: 1 offset for [x][y]: 4 offset for [y][x]: 4 offset for [y*SIZE+x]: 4
x: 2 y: 1 offset for [x][y]: 7 offset for [y][x]: 5 offset for [y*SIZE+x]: 5
x: 0 y: 2 offset for [x][y]: 2 offset for [y][x]: 6 offset for [y*SIZE+x]: 6
x: 1 y: 2 offset for [x][y]: 5 offset for [y][x]: 7 offset for [y*SIZE+x]: 7
x: 2 y: 2 offset for [x][y]: 8 offset for [y][x]: 8 offset for [y*SIZE+x]: 8
```

the last two results are using exactly the same semantics, the first one will let the compiler emit the calculation, but performance should be the same.

Additionally, once your data is arranged correctly, depending on what you do with the data, you may want to use OpenCL or something and utilize the GPU or SIMD, may lead significant performance improvements if can be expressed in SIMD (Single Instruction Multiple Data) code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
        _declspec(align(64))    unsigned char  block_hashfp;
#else
        __attribute__((aligned(64))) unsigned char  block_hashfp;
#endif
```

will hit l2 cache

Comment: Please clarify how aligning memory to 64 bit boundary will ensure that the memory is in the cache.

Comment: 64 byte. http://e-maxx.ru/bookz/files/intel_optimization.pdf

Comment: Note there is now a standard way to find the alignments [`std::hardware_destructive_interference_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size)

Comment: @Mgetz it prints 64 in their example. but why they're talking about `level 1` cache idk. 64 will work anyway

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин because for the direct intended purpose of that functionality L1 would be the target. Because that's where the initial hit of false sharing would occur. The fact that it happens to align with cache line size is just a nice convenience of how false sharing works.

Comment: @Mgetz you mean L0 most probably. https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/188776-how-l1-and-l2-cpu-caches-work-and-why-theyre-an-essential-part-of-modern-chips   And 64 is for L2 lines